# Accessing JSON body of POST request in Symfony 2.3 controller

Tags: php, symfony, post, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I've spent the past 3 hours attempting to parse the JSON body of an incoming POST request to an API endpoint I've built in Symfony 2.3.3.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get access to the body, and it is driving me mad. I have a graveyard full of syntaxes I've tried, and none of them have worked. Everything that has not worked is below.

Post request:

```
app_1    | Accept:          application/json
app_1    | Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
app_1    | Connection:      close
app_1    | Content-Length:  19
app_1    | Content-Type:    application/json
app_1    | Host:            localhost
app_1    | User-Agent:      Faraday v0.15.4
app_1    | X-Php-Ob-Level:  1
app_1    |
app_1    | {"hello":"goodbye"}
```

Inside controller default action (everything that has not worked):

```
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $hello = $request->query->get('hello');
        $hello1 = $request->request->get('hello');
        $hello2 = $request->get('hello');

        $json2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hello', FILTER_DEFAULT);
```

Whenever I error_log() any of the above variables, I get blank or nil.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
      $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
}
```

You can use `php://input`but it's inefficient.

Comment: It turns out you were correct, please edit your answer and I'll upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: I downvoted your answer because I thought it refered to a different version of Symfony—SO won't let me change my vote to an upvote unless you edit your answer :)